# Rename the index.php to others then how to do in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

now, i rename the `index.php` to `home.php`, when i click the category link, it will all handled by `example.com/index.php` 。so all the link aren't work. how to correct it? how to make home.php handle all the page. thank u

Comment: Have you got permalinks turned on?

Comment: yeap, i turned on the permalinks to http://example.com/sample-post/ all the post links are ok.but the example.com/home.php not ok. if i set to http://example.com/?p=123 all the links not ok. the example.com/home.php is ok.

Comment: the home page content is form themes -mythem - index.php

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to modify your .htaccess file in the root directory. It has a rewrite rule to point everything at index.php. Change it to point to home.php.

Something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Options All -Indexes

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress i put the code but it not work.

Comment: thank you,if i don't use .htaccess file . is there a way to get this?

Comment: I don't understand ? Wordpress requires that you use .htaccess, it doesn' work without it.

Comment: nope,i found the default wordpress zip package not have  .htaccess file.

Comment: if i don't use .htaccess file.i want to get that effect,how do i do?

Comment: It creates it as part of the install process.

Comment: You need a .htaccess file for wordpress to work. Why are you renaming index.php anyway ?

Comment: i want to add a flash to my site. when the user open the site, it shows a flash, then after some minutes redirect the home page

Comment: now, i migrate the host to lamp. i put the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home.php [L]
</IfModule>  in .hactess.some invoke of  the home page can't work.